# confused with disjoint unions

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

i am trying to have union of possible objects and to transform one to another

but both typescript and flow fail to recognize that boolean is true or false and nothing else and it's ok to assign boolean to object onion where it needs ether true literal or false literal

```
type Aa = {
  isFetching: false,
  isFailed: false,
  isFetched: false
}

type Bb = {
  isFetching: true,
  isFailed: false,
  isFetched: false
}

type Cc = {
  isFetching: true,
  isFailed: true,
  isFetched: false
}
type Dd = {
  isFetching: false,
  isFailed: true,
  isFetched: false
}

type Data = Aa | Bb | Cc | Dd

function thisWorks(data: Data): Data {
  if (data.isFailed) {
    return {
      isFetching: true,
      isFailed: true,
      isFetched: data.isFetched
    }
  } else {
    return {
      isFetching: true,
      isFailed: false,
      isFetched: data.isFetched
    }
  }
}

function thisDoesNot(data: Data): Data {
  return {
    isFetching: true,
    isFailed: data.isFailed,
    isFetched: data.isFetched
  }
}
```

is this bug or not?

[flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAggQxgXhgb2DGBLAzgMShAGMALbAOwHMAuGAMwQBtcoAaTHAhbJqAEzqMW7TnkIlSAoc1bAAvsFCRYAIQBGKdGIJEylWjBAAnAK6is4nn0ENZFrhLLS7IhUvDQYAYWJaMlrqSBnQm5hyB+NYuYQ7ielK2wnKKnrAAIvz+Ok7k1DIiEY7RtrFF8ZIuyVDuyl7pCCBIqIgwAD4wGu0+fh2ZSvSmFMQg2AD2FEbkuADqY8YA1rgAFPyNCHQNTQCUm+valvQwq+sAdFa8AtsHWDDGRKbGkwG3kQkhRmYOrxc2oV9FH5BZy2NZNc7AxKcLCKGEwKAiG5Ye4gR7PaG3Cr6fKfcIYyIlAqsQGYyEuMEICG5AQY2EwRSKYCDYajCZTPDpMZQXAAOTGIBOTT2O2FSBeKLRSMc7xxZQxv3JZwV-BJWMSdApVISNJhtSUwCAA)

[typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Aa%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20isFetching%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20isFailed%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20isFetched%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Bb%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20isFetching%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20isFailed%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20isFetched%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Cc%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20isFetching%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20isFailed%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20isFetched%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20Dd%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20isFetching%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20isFailed%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20isFetched%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Data%20%3D%20Aa%20%7C%20Bb%20%7C%20Cc%20%7C%20Dd%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20thisWorks(data%3A%20Data)%3A%20Data%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(data.isFailed)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isFetching%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isFailed%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isFetched%3A%20data.isFetched%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isFetching%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isFailed%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20isFetched%3A%20data.isFetched%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20thisDoesNot(data%3A%20Data)%3A%20Data%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFetching%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFailed%3A%20data.isFailed%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFetched%3A%20data.isFetched%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the object literal is compatible with neither `Bb` or `Cc`, since `isFailed` is `boolean` (since the field is common to all members of the union it will become `true|false` which is `boolean`)

The simplest solution is to use a type assertion to the union. This will preserve some checks but allow the assignment to occur:

```
function thisDoesNot(data: Data): Data {
    return {
        isFetching: true,
        isFailed: data.isFailed,
        isFetched: data.isFetched
    } as Data
}
```

this would be an error:

```
function thisDoesNot(data: Data): Data {
    return {
        isFetching: 1,
        isFailed: data.isFailed,
        isFetched: data.isFetched
    } as Data
}
```

We do lose excess property checks though, this would be valid:

```
function thisDoesNot(data: Data): Data {
    return {
        excess: 1,
        isFetching: true,
        isFailed: data.isFailed,
        isFetched: data.isFetched
    } as Data
}
```

Comment: casting object to Data does not fix this in flow

Comment: And it's still very weird to cast object to return type since it should be casted to it in ether way

Comment: @thecotne my answer is valid for typescript only not flow, I assumed your question was for typescript. It's a blind spot of the type system, its playing it too safe for a case that is valid.